# Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo umlauts and accents. I have searched, yet not found. Anywhere

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 19.04, language-support, layout

I have searched far and wide, yet I am confronted in GNOME on 19.04 with the fact that I cannot get umlauts etc to work. I have 2 kali (KDE) machines, on which I can get it to work quite easily. However, in this case, under Settings - devices - typing column - to find the "compose" key - is not there...
I've edited etc/default/console-setup to include 
XKBOPTIONS="compose:Shift+AltGr"
but I am sort of afraid to reboot, in fear that I might break something. Also it does not seem like the correct way since setting this functionality has been standard on previous versions of ubuntu etc.

This question has been asked many times, and has been solved many times, which is how I solved the umlaut problem on Kali/KDE too (since I am quite new on linux). Have tried linux many times in the past but only now it sticks. Any problems I have had up to now I have been able to solve without asking but this one is beyond me.

Am going to reboot now anyway, I guess I will have to.

If I don't return shortly, something broke. Otherwise, I'll be back soon ;-)

Thanks!

returned, system did not break aaannndd.... trying... e 
No joy. Pressing the AltGr key just shows the firefox menu bar.

I'm lost.

Comment: So your question is: "How do I define a compose key?" and you find the answer [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en#compose).

Comment: ë
Yay!!!! Thank you!!! So this was a typical issue of GNOME n00bness. Did not even know about the existence of Tweaks. That should have come up during my search, right? Will Backtrack to see where that went wrong. 
Anyway, I did a little dance for you! ;-)

Comment: Hmm... I can't mark your response as "The Answer", I think since it is posted as a comment?

Comment: That's true. But since this question has been asked before, I have voted for it to be considered a duplicate instead.

Comment: When refreshing this page, I got the question if another thread answered the question and included a link to that thread. I have marked this as a duplicate too and it will redirect to that thread now. Nice system. Very cool. 
Anyway, thank you, again, very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Ralt+"+o : ö  (that's right-alt, then ", then o)
Ralt+"+A : Ä
```

etc

also:

```
Ralt+s+s: ß
Ralt+e+=: €
Ralt+L+=: ₤
```

Comment: Sadly, that did not fly, tried it already. Gunnar's link helped out though. The tweak panel had to be installed for GNOME. 
Thanks though!